# Get/Display API data at front end from an API created in Django using Django-REST-Framework in an HTML page or Template

Tags: jquery, json, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am working with Django for quite some time but only at the basic backend level. Now I have started using DRF or Django-REST-Framework for creating an API and this is a new thing for me. I have successfully made an API using it and tested it using Postman by hitting on the URL for the data. My app is sending data as JSON. Problem is that I am unable to find a tutorial or link to see how can I consume this API data at front end. How can I send requests to get the data and then make a form to save data at the back end.

Models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields= ('created_by', 'question', 'pub_date')
```

views.py

```
class PollDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PollSerializer
    queryset = Poll.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

urls.py

```
path('polls/<int:pk>/', views.PollDetail.as_view(), name='poll_detail_api'),
```

And My results are somewhat like this

```
{
    "created_by": "shady",
    "question": "how do you deploy Django on Heroku?",
    "pub_date": "2019-08-20T09:05:11.113437Z"
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

ALso **How can I send information to authenticate users using Tokens saved in my DB?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Which front-end technology will you use ?

- If you want to use AngularJS you can check [here](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial)
- If you want to use React  check [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLRM7ROnmA9FxCtnLoIHAs6hIkJyd1dEx) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIFqqdRxmVo)
- If you want to use **Ajax** check **[here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLRM7ROnmA9Hjdjx1AxyY9JGrVknfWl1Y)**

Comment: But what if I do not want to use any of these. The are the frameworks only. Can't is be done without using some frameworks or libraries. Someone told me it can be done using jQuery only.

Comment: You can use jquery and  pure javascript as well. Here is jquery example for you -> https://medium.com/@_christopher/basic-web-app-with-django-rest-framework-and-jquery-ajax-c3a6a2ce3188

Comment: somehow I am able to show the data as [object Object]. Please tell me how can I render it into text? I am using a very simple html page.  **$.get( "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-api/polls/2/", function( data ) {
                    $( ".result" ).text( data );
                    alert( "Load was performed." );**